# "Invalid texture" error from SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface()?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, sdl

I keep getting this issue when I run my program. My images fail to load in with the  error: "Invalid texture". The program used to work fine. I'm working on it in linux ubuntu with all of my drivers updated. Here is the code where the renderer is made and the images are loaded.

//init.h

```
//#pragma once

#ifndef INIT_H
#define INIT_H


static const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 480;
static const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

static SDL_Surface* currentSurface = NULL;
static SDL_Window* window = NULL;
static SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;
static SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
//static SDL_Surface *SDL_SetVideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, SDL_ANYFORMAT);



bool init();
void close();

//void SetColor(int value);

#endif // INIT_H
```

//init.cpp

```
//#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include "tchar.h"
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "init.h"
#include "load.h"
//#include <conio.h>
//#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <cmath>



bool init()
{
    bool boot = 1;
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    {
        //SetColor(4);
        printf("SDL failed to initialize \n");
        //SetColor(7);
        boot = 0;
    }
    else {
        printf("SDL initialized!\n");
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Light Development Project", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
        if (window == NULL)
        {
            //SetColor(4);
            printf("SDL failed to create the window \n");
            //SetColor(7);
            boot = 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("Window created!\n");
            //screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
            printf("Screen surface created!\n");
        }
        printf("Initializing SDL_image...\n");
        int imgFlags = IMG_INIT_PNG;
        if (!(IMG_Init(imgFlags) & imgFlags))
        {
            //SetColor(4);
            printf("Failed to initialize SDL_image\n");
            //SetColor(7);
            boot = 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("SDL_image initialized!\n");
        }

        printf("Initializing TTF...\n");

        if (TTF_Init() == -1)
        {
            //SetColor(4);
            printf("Failed to initialize TTF\n");
            //SetColor(7);
            boot = 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("TTF initialized!\n");
        }


        printf("Creating renderer...\n");
        renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
        if (renderer == NULL)
        {
            //SetColor(4);
            printf("Failed to create renderer. Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            //SetColor(7);
            boot = 0;
        } else
        printf("Renderer created!\n");
        printf("Setting render draw color...\n");
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
        printf("Render draw color set!\n");
    }
    //printf("Done!\n");
    return boot;
}

void close()
{
    printf("\nShutting down...\nFreeing SDL surfaces...\nDetroying textures and renderers...\n");
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    texture = NULL;
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    renderer = NULL;
    printf("SDL surfaces, textures, and renderers freed from memory!\nDestroying SDL window...\n");
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    //TTF_CloseFont(font);
    //font = NULL;

    window = NULL;
    printf("SDL window detroyed!\nQuitting SDL subsystems...\n");
    IMG_Quit();
    SDL_Quit();
    //TTF_Quit();
    printf("All SDL subsystems shutdown!\n");
}

/*void SetColor(int value) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), value);
    /*
    1: Blue
    2: Green
    3: Cyan
    4: Red
    5: Purple
    6: Yellow (Dark)
    7: Default white
    8: Gray/Grey
    9: Bright blue
    10: Brigth green
    11: Bright cyan
    12: Bright red
    13: Pink/Magenta
    14: Yellow
    15: Bright white

}
*/
```

//load.h

```
//#pragma once

#ifndef LOAD_H
#define LOAD_H




enum KeyPressSurfacese
{
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFUALT,
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP,
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DOWN,
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT,
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_RIGHT,
    KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL
};

class cTexture {
public:
    cTexture();
    ~cTexture();

    bool loadFromFile(std::string path);

    void free();

    void render(int x, int y, SDL_Rect* clip = NULL, double angle = 0.0, SDL_Point* center = NULL, SDL_RendererFlip flip = SDL_FLIP_NONE);

    void loadFromRenderedText(std::string text, SDL_Color color);

    void setColor(Uint8 red, Uint8 green, Uint8 blue);

    void setBlendMode(SDL_BlendMode blending);

    void setAlpha(Uint8 alpha);

    int getWidth();

    int getHeight();

private:
    SDL_Texture * hTexture;
    int hWidth;
    int hHeight;
};

static cTexture keyPresses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_TOTAL];
static cTexture sprite;
static cTexture text;

static SDL_Texture* loadTexture(std::string path);
static SDL_Rect spriteClips[4];
//TTF_Font* font = NULL;
static SDL_Color textColor = { 0, 0, 0 };

void loadAssets();

#endif //LOAD_H
```

//load.cpp

```
//#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include "tchar.h"
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "init.h"
#include "load.h"
//#include <conio.h>
//#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <cmath>



cTexture::cTexture()
{
    //printf("Constructing texture wrapper class...\n");
    hTexture = NULL;
    hWidth = 0;
    hHeight = 0;
}
cTexture::~cTexture()
{
    //printf("Destroying texture wrapper class...\n");
    free();
 }



 void cTexture::free()
 {
    //if (hTexture != NULL)

        SDL_DestroyTexture(hTexture);
        hTexture = NULL;
        hWidth = 0;
        hHeight = 0;

 }

bool cTexture::loadFromFile(std::string path)
{
    free();
    SDL_Texture* newTexture = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* loadedSurface = IMG_Load(path.c_str());
    newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedSurface);
    if(newTexture == NULL)
    //printf("fail. error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    hWidth = loadedSurface->w;
    hHeight = loadedSurface->h;
    SDL_FreeSurface(loadedSurface);
    hTexture = newTexture;

    return hTexture != NULL;
}

void cTexture::render(int x, int y, SDL_Rect * clip, double angle, SDL_Point * center, SDL_RendererFlip flip)
{
    //SDL_Rect renderQuad = { x, y, hWidth, hHeight };
    SDL_Rect renderQuad = { x, y, 480, 480 };

    if (clip != NULL)
    {
        renderQuad.w = clip->w;
        renderQuad.h = clip->h;
    }

    SDL_RenderCopyEx(renderer, hTexture, clip, &renderQuad, angle, center, flip);
}

/*
void cTexture::loadFromRenderedText(std::string text, SDL_Color color)
{
    free();

    SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, text.c_str(), textColor);
    hTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, textSurface);
    hWidth = textSurface->w;
    hHeight = textSurface->h;
    SDL_FreeSurface(textSurface);
}
*/

void cTexture::setColor(Uint8 red, Uint8 green, Uint8 blue)
{
    SDL_SetTextureColorMod(hTexture, red, green, blue);
}

void cTexture::setBlendMode(SDL_BlendMode blending)
{
    SDL_SetTextureBlendMode(hTexture, blending);
}

void cTexture::setAlpha(Uint8 alpha)
{
    SDL_SetTextureAlphaMod(hTexture, alpha);
}

int cTexture::getWidth() { return hWidth; }
int cTexture::getHeight() { return hHeight; }



void loadAssets()
{

    printf("Loading image assets in loadAssets()...\n");

    if (!keyPresses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DEFUALT].loadFromFile("carrot.png"))
    {
        //SetColor(4);
        printf("Failed to load image. Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        //SetColor(7);
    } else
    printf("Image loaded\n");


    if(!keyPresses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP].loadFromFile("smIamLU.jpg"))
    {
        //SetColor(4);
        printf("Failed to load image\n");
        //SetColor(7);

    }
    else {
        //keyPresses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_UP].setBlendMode(SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND);
        printf("Image loaded\n");

    }

    if(!keyPresses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_DOWN].loadFromFile("down.bmp"))
    {
        //SetColor(4);
        printf("Failed to load image\n");
        //SetColor(7);

    } else
    printf("Image loaded\n");


    if(!keyPresses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_LEFT].loadFromFile("left.bmp"))
    {
        //SetColor(4);
        printf("Failed to load image\n");
        //SetColor(7);

    }else
    printf("Image loaded\n");


    if(!keyPresses[KEY_PRESS_SURFACE_RIGHT].loadFromFile("right.bmp"))
    {
        //SetColor(4);
        printf("Failed to load image\n");
        //SetColor(7);

    }else
    printf("Image loaded\n");


    if (!sprite.loadFromFile("foo.png"))
    {
        //SetColor(4);
        printf("Failed to load image\n");
        //SetColor(7);
    }else
    printf("Image loaded\n");


    spriteClips[0].x = 0;
    spriteClips[0].y = 0;
    spriteClips[0].w = 64;
    spriteClips[0].h = 205;

    spriteClips[1].x = 64;
    spriteClips[1].y = 0;
    spriteClips[1].w = 64;
    spriteClips[1].h = 205;

    spriteClips[2].x = 128;
    spriteClips[2].y = 0;
    spriteClips[2].w = 64;
    spriteClips[2].h = 205;

    spriteClips[3].x = 192;
    spriteClips[3].y = 0;
    spriteClips[3].w = 64;
    spriteClips[3].h = 205;


    //font = TTF_OpenFont("Ubuntu-L.ttf", 28);
    //text.loadFromRenderedText("text", textColor);


    printf("Done!\n");

}
```

With the renderer I've tried making it with differnt flags such as SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED or SDL_RENDERER_SOFTWARE but neither work. The error is specifically coming from the load.cpp file

```
newTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, loadedSurface);
```

This is the line that fails. The error generated by SDL reads "Invalid texture". The renderer is declared correctly but I can't get it to work.

I'm so confused why it isn't working because it used to work fine. I abandoned the project for a few months and it was working when I stopped, came back, and now it doesn't work. Not to mention that I had a bunch of more problems that I already worked out, but this one I can't.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [“Invalid texture” error from SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470076/invalid-texture-error-from-sdl-createtexturefromsurface)

Comment: I had to repost because no one helped me last time. I really need to figure this problem out

Comment: It seems like this should be reproducible with a short `main` in a single source file. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: What, no changes from previous question? Okay, here we go again. Your `renderer` is NULL. Your static variables in header files make no sense at all. Static function declaration in header file is even less reasonable. Consider proof-reading your source files and trying to answer "why is it here" at each keyword. If you want to share variable between multiple translation units, declare it `extern` and define it without qualifiers, stating that "renderer is declared correctly" doesn't make it so. Also it was a nice opportunity to learn how to use debugger.

Comment: Extern doesn't work. It gives me a multiple declaration error. And the renderer isn't NULL

Comment: @StrafeStopper it is NULL because statics are zero-initialised. Extern can't be "multiple declaration" because it is exactly for that purpose, but you need to define variable in exactly one translation unit. Please attach modified fragment and error message to question if you have problem with that.

Comment: How do i get the variables to work then? As soon as I switch it to extern it gives me a multiple declaration error and I can't compile it

Comment: @StrafeStopper `extern SDL_Renderer *renderer` in header, `SDL_Renderer *renderer` in e.g. `init.cpp`. The same for all other global variables.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and it's the strangest fix I've ever done. I added an error check for the renderer in the load function and it started working again. If I remove the error check if statement it goes back to not working. Seems like a strange bug but I'm glad it's working again.